# How to get new lines to display on Dispwin?

Tags: javascript, html

Shown below I am try to input text into a text area and output it into a new window. My problem is I can't seem to get a new line to show in my DispWin when I click enter on the keyboard.

```
  <script>
        function display() {
            // open a new window with specific properties
            const DispWin = window.open('', 'NewWin', 'toolbar=no,status=no,width=700,height=500');

            

            // create an array of the form elements
            const formElements = [
                document.form1.activity,
                document.form1.des,
                document.form1.trouble,
            ];

            // create an array of the form labels
            const formLabels = [
                "Activity",
                "Description",
                "Troubleshooting Steps",
            ];

            // create an empty string to store the message
            let message = "<ul style='list-style-type:none;font-family:sans-serif;'>";

            // loop through the form elements and add them to the message string
            for (let i = 0; i < formElements.length; i++) {
                message += `<li style='margin-bottom:5px;'><b>${formLabels[i]}:</b> ${formElements[i].value}</li>`;
            }

            message += "</ul>";

            // write the message to the new window
            DispWin.document.write(message);
        }
    </script>
```

My expected result should be when I go to DispWin is...

Activity: ***Activity Type**

Description: (Inputted text)

Troubleshooting Steps:(Inputted text) (Input From keyboard for a new line)
(Inputted text on a new line)

Comment: With popup blockers actively blocking window.open windows, using a modal in the parent window would be your best option.

Comment: Doesn't seems like popup blockers are affecting it. I'm able to open DispWin and get my inputted text. I'm Just having trouble getting it to create a new line when I input enter on my keyboard.

Comment: could you provide a working snippet. Your code is missing important inputs

Comment: @MehyarSawas here you go https://pastebin.com/43ux3KM1

Answer (score 0):

In the html standard new lines `\n` are handled like any other white space. Use [white-space: pre-line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#collapsing_of_white_space) which adds line breaks to the new lines.

```html
<li id="li-1" style='margin-bottom:5px; white-space: pre-line'></li>

<script>
document.getElementById('li-1').innerHTML = 'first\nsecond\nthird';
</script>
```